# Hatcher exercise 0.6(c)-continuity

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to show the continuity of the function defined in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166648/exercise-6-chapter-0-hatcher/945119#945119). But I don't know how to. Any hints or comments will be appreciated.