# contractible vs deformation retract to a point

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Deformation retraction to a point is a stronger condition,so is there a example of a contractible space that does't deformation retract onto any point?

Comment: Consider two dimensional sphere which can not be deformed into a point.

Comment: You can find example of such space in Hatcher’s (Algebraic topology) exercise

Comment: @HK Lee but why it's contractible?

Comment: Sorry. I confused with a retraction.

Comment: @HKLee. The sphere isn't contractible.

Comment: @MayureshL write an answer referring to the exact page of the example, e.g.

Comment: some googling reveiled [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/495856/4280)

Comment: Some relevant answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166648/why-does-the-zig-zag-comb-weakly-deformation-retract-onto-a-point https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126342/why-doesnt-the-zig-zag-comb-deformation-retract-onto-a-point-even-though-it

Comment: @Henno Brandsma well,it's a nice example

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913383/x-is-contractible-if-and-only-if-there-exists-a-deformation-retract-to-a-point/2913423#2913423